# How to access/print fields in non-Drupal php files?

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm using Drupal's php filter to add php code in node body of some of my nodes. Among other things, I'm also including a php file. That php file is doing some non-Drupal work and it is included in those nodes properly. However, I can't print Drupal's fields in that file.

Here is an example of php code in node's body field:

```
<?php

some work is happening here

include 'non-drupal.php'; // include non-drupal php file

some work is happening here

?>
```

Here is an example of non-drupal.php:

```
<?php

echo date('h:i:s'); // This works

print $title; // This doesn't work

?>
```

When I open that node, I can see the time, but there's no node title displayed.

Is it possible to print node fields from "external" php files?

EDIT (code added from [dropbucket](http://dropbucket.org/node/756)) I have tried with adding this code from Dropbucket, but it's not working either):

```
<?php

echo date('h:i:s'); // This works

function get_node_title($nid) {
return db_query('SELECT title FROM {node} WHERE nid = :nid', array(':nid' => $nid))->fetchField();
} // This doesn't work (There is no output, but no errors displayed either)

?>
```

Comment: What is your goal with that file?

Comment: It's doing some non-Drupal work, but in some cases I need to use Drupal's fields in it to make it work properly.

Comment: Either you could overwrite node.tpl.php, create your own module or use [drupal_bootstrap](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_bootstrap/7).

Answer (score 2):

You could try it with [drupal_bootstrap](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_bootstrap/7), but it is not tested.

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', '/path/to/drupal');
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

$title = drupal_get_title();
echo $title;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to used [GLOBALS](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/7) ? or drupal_get_title() ?

EDIT : Can you try instead :

```
$title = drupal_get_title()
// use your variable $title
```

Comment: I'm not sure what should I do with GLOBALS, but get_title might be what I'm after. What code exactly should I use? I have tried the code at http://dropbucket.org/node/756, but it's not working either.

Comment: @take2 What code did you try? What did it do to make you think it won't work?

Comment: @Clive I have tried the code at dropbucket that I have linked to (function get_node_title...). It didn't output node title.

Comment: If your code's not here, it's invisible (makes sure we don't have questions that rely on code in a 3rd party site that will inevitably be removed at some point). Please edit the question and provide full details of where you're stuck. I think I can guess, but no sense wasting time if I'm wrong

Comment: @clive I have updated the question.

Comment: @IsmaH I have tried with `$title = drupal_get_title(); echo $title;`, but it just loads forever and doesn't include non-drupal.php.

Comment: @IsmaH Also, the problem with get_title approach is that it, as far as I understand it, can output only the title. However, I need to access different fields, just like it's possible in node.tpl.php

Comment: have you configured this page /admin/config/content/formats/php_code ?